# Mirroring Windows 7 install to migrate to a new disk

Tags: windows-7, migration

One of my clients has a critical Windows 7 workstation, due to the variety of software installed on the machine, 'extremely' intricate software setup, and it's critical nature to the business it needs to be migrated to a new smaller SSD disk intact (and double quick).

[This question addresses the problem for a server solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/143767/migrate-windows-server-2008-to-a-new-hard-disk) but does the accepted question's advice hold for a simple workstation.

Whichever solution is proposed it needs to be bullet proof and take <4 hours to perform or the client's business will being loosing a substantial amount of money per hour!

The reason for the migration is failing hardware.

Comment: If an outage results in a large cost, then maybe you should look for a tool that will make and keep an up-to-date image backup while the system is live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its that critical then I also wouldn't bother moving it to a single SSD (yet again a single point of failure).  At the least I would migrate it to a RAID 5 set.  However what you should really do is get rolling with virtualization and use a P to V (physical to virtual) migration tool to capture the workstation in a VM.  You can then live replicate the VM and keep it in sync with the captured VM for recovery/fail over.

Comment: Good advice. I've had this conversation with them, this is something that came up last night and needs to be fixed this weekend. They are going to look at failover, and better strategies next week but for now the immediate problem need to be taken care of.